# Add reverse shadow and elevation to the CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I have a `CollapsingToolbar` with a header image. I want to add a shadow on the image, not below. I tried the `app:elevation` parameter but it had no effect.

Screenshots:

[Layout now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGxX.jpg)

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Wt9.jpg)

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include layout="@layout/detail_content"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewToolbar"
            android:minHeight="500dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:title=""
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fullscreenFAB"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_black_24dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your ImageVIew and ProgressBar into a RelativeLayout and add a View with a shadow background into it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

   <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewToolbar"
        android:minHeight="500dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


         <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient" />

          </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:title=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Also create a "gradient.xml" file into drawable folder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@color/translucent_grey"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
```